# Python serial module prints empty lines

Tags: python, linux, arduino, pyserial

I'm trying to make an Arduino code that generates random numbers and a Python program that reads those numbers from serial and prints them in the command line.

This is my Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
}

void loop() {
    long rand = random(10);
    Serial.println(rand);
    delay(1000);
}
```

and this is my Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600, timeout = 1)
if ser.is_open == 0:
    ser.open()
    print('serial was not open, so it is open now')
else:
    print('serial was open this whole time')
while ser.is_open:
    thing = ser.readline()
    print(thing)
    #ser.readline()
ser.close()
```

Once the Arduino starts making random numbers, I run my Python program and I get the following output:

```
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

I was expecting to see random numbers instead of `b''`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'd expect code to setup the serial communication in a Arduino sketch.

Comment: Hi Klaus, yeah, I added `Serial.begin(9600)` to void setup, and it works, I now get some random numbers being printed to the screen. However, the format is a bit odd, the numbers are showing up as `b'8\r\n'`. Do you know how I could fix this format so that only the number is showing up?

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised the serial object in the arduino code

Try this change in the setup function in your Arduino code.

```
setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
```

and next time you have a similar problem try modular checks. First check if the Arduino is doing it's job or not, and then check if the whole system is working or not.

Comment: Thanks Nitro, that did fix it, however, my numbers are now show up as `b '8\r\n'`, do you know how I could fix this format issue?

Comment: \r\n are a sent when you use the Serial.println.
Use Serial.print and it should work fine. BTW Serial.print will work fine only because you have a 1 second delay in your code, otherwise it will cause different problems. Also please mark my response as helpful, this improves my rankings here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I did mark your response as helpful, but when I click on the upward arrow, it goes to 1 then immediately back to 0, it says that I need to have at least a reputation of 15 for it to count publicly.